# Unity Editor Option Popup? ( Unity Editor update Option )

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

The problem is I have many different options that only happen once.
I have a dropdown menu that has two options. ( Slider, CheckBox )

!!Slider!! 
If the slider is selected I want to have the following options available in editor. ( MinValue, MaxValue, defaultValue)

!!CheckBox!! 
if checkbox is selected I want to have the following option in editor.
( Check )

z.b: [image: ttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bwf1NukaFKoc5EHji_9YG5BoADN3RJzP/view?usp=sharing]

I have already tried to influence the editor window. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.FadeGroupScope.html)
But since I only want to extend one option and do not want to create a new window, this option has not been very helpful.

**The question is, how do I design more options and take them away?** 
Unity version. 2018.4.8f1

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;




public class uitest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TestType { Slider, CheckBox };
    public TestType test = TestType.Slider;
    //[SerializeField]
    private bool Check = false;
    //[SerializeField]
    private int MinValue = 0;
    //[SerializeField]
    private int MaxValue = 3;
    //[SerializeField]
    private int defaultValue = 2;

}
```

Comment: What is the question? Also, please upload the image into the question instead of providing the link.

Comment: The question is, how do I design more options and take them away?

Comment: So you want to achieve what is show in Good image correct? Is that an edited image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide your own `Editor` for your type. Place it as `uitesteditor.cs` under directory named `Editor` somewhere in Assets.

With `public` members (or accessors) this code can be done without too much Unity voodoo.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(uitest))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class uitesteditor : Editor
{
    static string[] customProperties = new string[] { "Check", "MinValue", "MaxValue", "defaultValue" };
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        // Draw common properties (by excluding all custom ones)
        // Could be skipped if there is none such.
        DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject, customProperties);

        var uitarget = target as uitest;
        // Custom UI based on selected enum
        switch (uitarget.test)
        {
            case uitest.TestType.CheckBox:
                uitarget.Check = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Check", uitarget.Check);
                break;
            case uitest.TestType.Slider:
                uitarget.MinValue = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Min value", uitarget.MinValue);
                uitarget.MaxValue = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Max value", uitarget.MaxValue);
                uitarget.defaultValue = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Default value", uitarget.defaultValue);
                break;
        }

        // Needed only by DrawPropertiesExcluding
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

If you want to operate on private fields with `SerializeField` there is more boilerplate code needed. We use `SerializedProperty` instances to access `private` serialized fields, thus code may look less readable.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(uitest))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class uitesteditor : Editor
{
    static string[] customProperties = new string[] { "test", "Check", "MinValue", "MaxValue", "defaultValue" };
    SerializedProperty test, check, MaxValue, MinValue, defaultValue;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        test = serializedObject.FindProperty("test");
        check = serializedObject.FindProperty("Check");
        MinValue = serializedObject.FindProperty("MinValue");
        MaxValue = serializedObject.FindProperty("MaxValue");
        defaultValue = serializedObject.FindProperty("defaultValue");
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        // Draw common properties (by excluding all custom ones)
        DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject, customProperties);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(test);
        switch ((uitest.TestType)test.intValue)
        {
            case uitest.TestType.CheckBox:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(check);
                break;
            case uitest.TestType.Slider:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(MinValue);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(MaxValue);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(defaultValue);
                break;
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Note: I've added `CanEditMultipleObjects` tag, but you should decide on your own if it is desired. Rendered inspector GUI will use `test` enum value from first object selected.

Comment: Note that in the beginning of `OnInspectorGUI` you should also call `serializedObject.Update();` and remove the `if (GUI.changed)` check

Comment: You can also omit the `new GUIContent(...)` since `PropertyField` will automatically use the according field name. You only have to pass in `new GUIContent` if you want to have a customized different text displayed

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for hints, `GUIContent` and `Update()` sounds reasonable. I've added `if (GUI.changed)` based on `NVidia Flex` asset, where properties' setters do call heavy C-functions upon change. I though it should do no harm when normal setters are used.